Lost information after reading Svg with Svg.Net
I am working with SVG.NET in Visual Studio and trying to read the specific elements of an SVG.
When I read an SVG in debug or release mode from Visual Studio, everything works fine.
However, after I create an installation and try it without Visual Studio, some SVG data is lost. The input SVGs are exactly the same. The elements created from it via
SvgDocument.Open(svgFilePath);

or
SvgDocument.FromSvg<SvgDocument>(File.ReadAllText(svgPath));

do not display all the information of the SVG.
Below you can see some examples (example data). It is just the beginning of the document to show you the problem.
[A] is the SvgContent read via SvgNet in Visual Studio (Debug or Release) and plotted via svgDoc.GetXML(). [B] is exactly the same Svg input that is read by the installation. As you can see, the transforms, width, height, stroke-width and x,y values are missing.
I have already checked the following:

both refer to the exact same Svg.DLL
both work with the same .NET Framework 4.8 (v4.0.30319).
the input SVGs are exactly the same
System.Drawing is in the same version
I copied all missing DLLs from Visual Studio to the installation folder to make sure it is not a forgotten reference
both have the same settings for culture + ui-culture

If I read the elements in the installation via XmlDocument and log the InnerXML to a textfile the transforms etc. are displayed correctly.
I have no clue what I am missing or doing wrong.
Example data
[A] SVG Content read in Visual Studio (DEBUG or RELEASE), this is how it should be

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" width="1122.52" height="793.7008" viewBox="0, 0, 1122.52, 793.7008">
  <rect x="37.79527" y="75.59055" width="1046.929" height="680.3149" stroke-width="1.322835" fill-opacity="0" style="fill:white;stroke:black;" />
  <g transform="translate(404.4094, 604.7244)">
    <g>
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="170.0787" height="37.79527" stroke-width="1.322835" fill-opacity="0" stroke-opacity="0" style="fill:white;stroke:white;" />
      <text transform="translate(3.779528, 5.889764) translate(2, 0) translate(0, 3)" text-anchor="start" font-family="Segoe UI" font-size="10" style="dominant-baseline:hanging;fill:black;">TestText</text>
    </g>
(...)

[B] the same SVG Content read from the installation, missing informations
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" viewBox="0, 0, 1122.52, 793.7008">
  <rect fill-opacity="0" style="fill:white;stroke:black;" />
  <g>
    <g>
      <rect x="0" y="0" fill-opacity="0" stroke-opacity="0" style="fill:white;stroke:white;" />
      <text text-anchor="start" font-family="Segoe UI" font-size="10" style="dominant-baseline:hanging;fill:black;">TestText</text>
    </g>
(...)

Used Versions
NET Framework 4.8
SVG.net Version 3.4.7
Win 11
Visual Studio 2022 Professional.

Solved it : it was the missing system.numerics.vector.dll
